# string LIKE column in jOOQ

Tags: jooq

I've been looking for a way to implement the following query in jOOQ but couldn't find anything.

```
SELECT *
FROM   tableName
WHERE  'this is a string' LIKE CONCAT('%', word ,'%')
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two things worth mentioning here:

1. How to create a bind variable to the left of the `LIKE` predicate
2. How to creat the concatenation in SQL

#### 1. Bind variable

Just use [`DSL.val(String)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#val-java.lang.String-) for this, for example:

```java
Field<String> field = val("this is a string");
```

You can then use this in your query just like any other [`Field`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Field.html)

#### 2. Concatenation

Use the [`DSL.concat(Field...)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#concat-org.jooq.Field...-) method for this. E.g.:

```java
Field<String> concatenated = concat(inline("%"), TABLENAME.WORD, inline("%"));
```

Notice that I'm using [`DSL.inline(String)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#inline-java.lang.String-) here, not `val()` as this will create a string literal (inlined bind variable), not an ordinary bind variable. More info here:

https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/bind-values/inlined-parameters

#### Complete query:

```java
DSL.using(configuration)
   .selectFrom(TABLENAME)
   .where(val("this is a string").like(concat(
        inline("%"), TABLENAME.WORD, inline("%")
    )))
   .fetch();
```

Comment: Thanks @Lukas for the thorough explanation

Answer (score 0):

İt will work if you use like this

```
SELECT * FROM   TableName WHERE  ColumnName LIKE CONCAT('%','item', '%')
```

jOOQ  will be like this

`DSLContext create = DSL.using(connection, dialect);`

```
  CREATE.Select * .from(TableName).WHERE 
 (TableName.ColumnName.LIKE CONCAT ('%item%'))
 .EXECUTE()
```